# Scale cosine distance to 0-1 using Gensim

Tags: python, math, nlp, text-mining, gensim

I've built a Doc2Vec model with around 3M documents, now I want to compare it to another model I've previously built. The second model has been scaled to 0-1 so I now also want to scale the gensim model to the same range so that they are comparable.
This is my first time using gensim so I'm not sure how this is done. It's nothing fancy but this is the code I have so far (model generation code ommited). I thought about scaling (minmax scaling with max/min in the union of  vectors) the inferred vectors (v1 and v2) but I don't think this would be correct approach.
The idea here is to compare two documents (with tokens likely to be in the corpus) and output a similarity score between them. I've seen a few Gensim's tutorials and they often compare a single string to the corpus' documents, which is not really the idea here.

> ```
>  def get_similarity_score(self,string_1, string_2):
>     split_tokens1 = string_1.split()
>     split_tokens2 = string_2.split()
>     v1 = self.model.infer_vector(split_tokens1)
>     v2 = self.model.infer_vector(split_tokens2)
>     text_score = nltk.cluster.util.cosine_distance(v1, v2)
>     return text_score
> ```

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that 'cosine similarity' & 'cosine distance' are different things.

A cosine-similarity can range from `-1.0` to `1.0` – but in some models, such as those based only on positive word counts, you might only practically see values from `0.0` to `1.0`. But in both cases, items with similarities close to `1.0` are *most-similar*.

On the other hand, a cosine-distance can range from `0.0` to `2.0`, and items with a distance of `0.0` are *least-distant* (or *nearest*). A cosine-distance can be larger than `1.0` - but you might only see such distances in models which use the dense coordinate space (like `Doc2Vec`), not in word-count models which leave half the coordinate space empty (all negative coordinates).

So: you shouldn't really be calling your function `similarity` if it's returning a distance, and if it's now returning surprise numbers over `1.0`, there's nothing wrong: that's possible in some models, but not others.

You could naively rescale the `0.0` to `2.0` distances that your calculation will get with `Doc2Vec` vectors, with some crude hammer like:

```
new_distance = old_distance / 2
```

However, note that in general, the *absolute* similarities from different models are still not necessarily meaningfully comparable. This is even true between two diferent `Doc2Vec` models. Their magnitudes are highly influenced by things like the model-metaparameters.

For example, if you used the exact same sufficiently-large set of texts to train a 100-dimensional `Doc2Vec` model, and a 300-dimensional `Doc2Vec` model, both models might wind up very similarly-useful. And for a doc A, its nearest-neighbor might consistently be doc B. Indeed, its top-10 neighbors might be very similar or identical.

But the cosine-similarities may have far different maxes/ranges, like the same neighbor B having the similarity `0.9` in one but `0.6` in another. Thy're the same docs, and correctly identified as 'most-similar', and neither `0.9` or `0.6` is truly a worse number to report, because in both cases the proper most-similar doc is at the top of the rankings. The models have just wound up using the available coordinate space differently. So, you shouldn't compare that `0.6` or `0.9` similarity (or in your case other distance numbers) against some other model – *especially* if the models use different algorithms, as seems to be the case for you. (If looks like you may be comparing absolute cosine-distances from a word-counting model against a dense learned `Doc2Vec` model.)

It *may* make more sense to compare result-*rankings* between the models. That is, ignore the raw similarity numbers, but care whether desirable documents appear in the top-N for other documents.  Alternatively, it might be possible to learn some scaling-rule for making the distances more comparable, but it's hard to make a more specific recommendation, or even know if that's a good step to take, without knowing your ultimate goal in comparing the models.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Is this cosine similarity derived from "infer_vector"? I looked up different resources and was never sure if infer_vector outputs in the range of [-1,1]
The goal is not to directly compare the similarity, but to check for precison and recall against different cosine similarity threshold ranges (0-1). That's why I'd want to have a model that outputs in that range.

Comment: Also, which function should I use to calculate the cosine similarity? I tried with infer_vector but the cosine similarity was sometimes above 1...

Comment: `infer_vector()` only returns a full vector - it does no similarity-comparison. The `similarity()` method can compare 2 vectors in-the-model, by their keys (doc tag): https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/keyedvectors.html#gensim.models.keyedvectors.KeyedVectors.similarity - if you need to do you own vector-to-vector calc, you can use the definition of cosine-similarity – dot-product of normed vectors – as exemplified by the code for that lookup-based function: https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/5edc4113680ff349e1b1c591d066b9225de38433/gensim/models/keyedvectors.py#L1139

Comment: Yes exactly, I used infer_vector to get the vectors and then applied nltk.cluster.util.cosine_distance(v1, v2) for the cosine distance (I assume it's the same calculation), however some cosine distances were above 1.
I thought about applying similarity() however some of my documents will have tokens absent from the training corpus. I could potentially check if the tokens were in the corpus, and remove those that arent, but I'm not sure how efficient it would be to query the corpus for every single token...

Comment: Aha! I'd overlooked that you were mixing the terms 'similarity' (with a `0.0` to `1.0` range) & 'cosine-distance'. Cosine-similarity sometimes goes from `0.0` to `1.0` (in some constrained uses), other times `-1.0` to `1.0` – but always, the most-similar items have similarities close to `1.0`. 'Cosine distance', as offered by `nltk.cluster.util.cosine_distance()`, is a *different* calculation, where the nearest items have distances near `0.0`, & distances can range as high as `2.0` (but in some vector-spaces, especailly those with only non-negative word-counts, will never see values > `1.0`).

Comment: I wil update the answer text to be clearer with a recommendation given this.

Comment: Answer changed/expanded, please consider again.